# Writing a columned file text separated by an indentation in C++

Tags: c++, ofstream

I'm trying to write in a file some numbers separated by an indentation (c++) so I can read them after using Python by numpy loadtxt function. What is the most effective way to add an indentation in C++? I might think a comma should work too. This is what I have (not separated):

```
    ofstream qfit ;
    qfit.open("qfit.dat") ;
    qfit << freq_si <<star.mom_quad() << star.angu_mom() ;
    qfit.close();
```

Comment: Use a comma, a space, or a tab.  All should work.  CSV is a popular format.

Comment: You can specify the delimiter for [loadtext](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html).

Comment: Ok thanks both. Ill try with a comma changing the delimiter in loadtxt. But, just for knowledge, how to separate by a tab in C++?

Comment: @IsaacDomínguezLarrañaga Just output the tab character: `'\t'`

Comment: Thanks @NathanOliver. Reading some stuff in stackoverflow I got mad cause people were using their own functions. I was just looking for this info :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a '\t' or change the delimiter. By @NathanOliver